# OnSubscriptionError EWS double subscription

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am connecting to Exchange 2013 hosted on cloud and registering for streaming notifications using EWS (Exchange web service api). The issue is, at any random time, subscription throws error and i am handing OnSubscriptionError event. Here, i am removing all subscriptions and closing connection and connecting again.

As my connection and subscription is set, application start receiving multiple events. It looks like a case of double streaming subscription connection.

What is the best way to re-establish connection from point when OnSubscriptionError is fired?
Is there any way to see what causing OnSubscriptionError event to fire on Exchange side?

```
static void OnError(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            // Handle error conditions.  
            Exception e = args.Exception;
            CustomLogger.WriteErrorLog(String.Format("In OnError: " + Environment.NewLine + " Message:{0} " + Environment.NewLine + "Exception Message:{1} " + Environment.NewLine + "Inner Exception:{2} " + Environment.NewLine + "Source:{3} " + Environment.NewLine + "Stack Trace{4}",
                                                    ErrorMessages.GeneralError, e.Message, e.InnerException, e.Source, e.StackTrace), drawLines: true);
            StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = null;

            if (args.Subscription != null)
            {
                CustomLogger.WriteErrorLog(Messages.UnSubscribeToNotifications);
                try
                {
                    connection = (StreamingSubscriptionConnection)sender;
                    connection.RemoveSubscription(args.Subscription);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                CustomLogger.WriteErrorLog(Messages.UnSubscribedToNotifications);
            }
            if (connection != null && connection.IsOpen) connection.Close();

            ReConnectAndSubscribe();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I explicitly call the Unsubscribe function in the OnError function, unless the `ErrorCode` is `ErrorSubscriptionUnsubscribed` or `ErrorSubscriptionNotFound`.  Not sure if skipping this would result in double notifications or not, or even why they'd come in on another connection, but it might be good to throw that in there.

I'd also recommend not calling your `ReConnectAndSubscribe()` function in the event handler.  That could take some time, and the less done in a handler, the better, altho I can't imagine this is related.  Set a flag to re-sub and do it on the main thread.

As to figuring out why Exchange is doing this, I'd say give up that quest, especially if you're on O365.  My experience has been that "bad things" happen to subscriptions and connections in that environment very frequently, and all you can do is ride it out and keep on re-connecting.